# How to get grant staus from battery optimization permission popup

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-permissions

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-disable-battery-optimizations-android package for my React Native Android app. This package provides OpenBatteryModal() method to raise popup to get ignore battery optimization permission. But it does not provide how to get permission granted status. So, my question is "Is there any way to get to know what option is selected in permission popup or is there any other workaround in this package to get the grant status? I am struck on this for days. There is not much help also apart from using this package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this library (`RNDisableBatteryOptimizationsAndroid`) has a method to check the status of battery optimization, it's even mentioned on their README under [usage](https://github.com/rasheedk/react-native-disable-battery-optimizations-android#usage). I'm not sure what you've tried, but this is how you can check if the permission was granted using their `isBatteryOptimizationEnabled` API:

```
import RNDisableBatteryOptimizationsAndroid from 'react-native-disable-battery-optimizations-android';

RNDisableBatteryOptimizationsAndroid.isBatteryOptimizationEnabled().then((isEnabled)=>{
    if(isEnabled){
        RNDisableBatteryOptimizationsAndroid.openBatteryModal();
    }
});
```

You can't get the user selected option directly, so in case the above example is not enough - you can write some logic to get the status when your app becomes active (using react-native `AppState`) after the modal is closed; since the modal is a new activity you should be notified when your activity becomes active again. Optimize it so you only check the status if `openBatteryModal` was requested.

Comment: AppState is what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the answer. I am able to achieve what I want using AppState.

Comment: As of now I am handling getting the Deny/Allow response through AppState. But another problem is in Xiomi MIUI devices, first Allow/Deny popup comes and once we give Allow in the popup, It redirects to the settings to select No Restrictions option. In this scenario, I am always getting Deny response though user gives "No Restrictions" as once initial popup closes we get permission status as not granted. Is there any other solution to handle these kind of scenarios?